# Prestashop set a smarty variable on a hook

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I would like to assign a smarty variable on the hook `actionAuthentication` which get triggered when an user successfully connects and unset it whenever the user disconnects.

so I can manage my content depending on the connexion with a condition like the following :

```
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <p>Name :</p>
                {if $my_variable}
                    <span class="employee-name">{$my_variable}</span>
                {else}
                    <span class="employee-name">Firstname Lastname</span>
                {/if}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

How could I assign a global smarty variable from a hook ?

**Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work:**

```
public function hookActionAuthentication()
{

  $result = 'Myself';

  $this->context->smarty->assign([
      'my_variable' => $result
  ]);
}
```

Comment: This hook is triggered after customer successful authentication. First you need to check your hook is triggered or not. I mean some die or echo statement inside function to make sure your function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use hookActionAuthentication($params), you should assign $this->context->customer->fistname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname.
you can use function isLogged to check if customer is loggued or not

```
$this->context->customer->isLogged()
```